# List of all known implementations of IEnumerable in C#

Tags: c#, documentation

I try to find list of classes in C# which implement `IEnumerable<T>`. In Java documentation there is section "all known implementations". I need to find the same for C#.

Comment: You could probably use reflection to find them

Answer (score 4):

There is no such list in the language documentation.

Comment: I need to create instance of `IEnumerable` how do I know which class to choose if I don't even know any to choose from?

Comment: @ASPNET Start with List<T> If you need more specific behavior, look for general solutions to the problem you are trying to solve, other implementations will show up.

Comment: @ASPNET Well you'd find a list of I would imagine several thousand types would be on it, so I don't imagine that evaluating every single one of them would be a terribly productive solution to your problem.  Instead you should figure out what you actually want out of your sequence and then find/create a type that has those semantics.